# How to add the Google Core API dependency to an Android Studio Gradle project?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a project using a Firestore database. In their examples, I need a function call they seem to be getting out of the "ApiFuture" container class, as in [these examples.](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/firestore/src/main/java/com/example/firestore/Quickstart.java)

However, the com.google.api.core module is not by default in my project. I've tried googling it and searching StackOverflow, but all I've found is suggestions to add

```
implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
```

But this only adds the com.google.api.client module, which as far as I can tell does not include the ApiFuture class. So how do I go about including this?

All I'm trying to do is getting all documents from a Collection in Firestore, but this doesn't seem possible from the Task class that Android Studio by default puts QuerySnapshots in, which is why I want to try the ApiFuture class that's used in the aforementioned github examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to add a server SDK to your Android app.  That's not right.  If you want to use Firestore in your Android app, you should use the Android SDK.  [Follow the instructions here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) to get started, and be sure to select the Android tab (not the Java tab).

Comment: I'm already using Firestore in my android app, that's not the issue. Selecting the "Android" tab helped me find the issue though, apparently there are separate methods for doing it in java applications and doing it for Android with java.

Comment: Doug, thank you for clarifying this.  I spent 30 minutes trying to figure this out!